# active_admin and has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have two models with following associations:

```
class Panel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
end


class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :panel
end
```

And I'm using active_admin to manage surveys:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Survey do
  config.per_page = 20

  actions :index, :edit, :update

  index do
    column 'Survey ID' do |s|
      s.id
    actions defaults: true
  end

  form do |f|
    inputs do
      input :id, input_html: { disabled: true }
    end
    f.actions
  end
end
```

And now I want to add a field to form to have possibility to change survey panel. I read through all documentation of active_admin but didn't find any similar case... Is this possible to do with ActiveAdmin?

Comment: Did you try this `f.inputs do |t| t.has_one :panel end` ?

Comment: It returns me:
undefined method `has_one' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I'm sorry its f inside the loop as well. `f.inputs do f.has_one :panel end`

Comment: Still doesnt work:
undefined method `has_one' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::ActiveAdminForm:0x0000000a0b68c8>

Comment: I guess you should be using has_many only inside. It says so in Wiki. Check Nested Resources comment in the following url. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/5-forms.md#nested-resources

Comment: You can create forms with nested models using the has_many method, even if your model uses has_one. Thats what wiki says.

Comment: I was trying something like that:
    f.inputs do
      f.has_many :qualtrics_panel, heading: 'Themes', allow_destroy: true, new_record: false do |a|
        a.input :id
      end
    end
but this returns me:
undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82608/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-mateusz-urbanski).

Comment: Actually you were accessing just new_record. But, why does the error say new_record? with a question mark...

Comment: Are you trying to add a new record. Then the new_record should be some string not false.

Comment: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3978

Comment: Thank you for help. I will rewrite my association to has_many and belongs_to.

Comment: You can write nested form for :has_one specifically, check this answer out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159884/rails-activeadmin-nested-form-has-one-accepts-attributes-for-formtastic-issue

Answer (score 2):

> You can create forms with nested models using the has_many method, even if your model uses has_one

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/9c46b14ea0d9b3aaaa3d7520555c9959d06ce7f3/docs/5-forms.md#nested-resources