# undefined method `collection_id' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, has-many-through, formtastic

I have 3 models `Category`, `Collection` and `Cat`

Here is my associations:

```
class Category
  has_one :cat
  has_one :collection, through: :cat
end

class Collection
  has_many :cats
  has_many :categories, through: :cats
end

class Cat
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :collection
end
```

Trying to assign fields with formtastic (ActiveAdmin):

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors

    f.input :collection

    f.inputs
    f.actions
  end
end
```

/edit page gives me following error:

```
undefined method `collection_id' for #<Category:0x007f8590b4a768>
```

How can I assign records with this relation? Is it possible?

Update. Here is the schema

```html
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151006174748) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  enable_extension "hstore"

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
  end

  create_table "cats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.integer "collection_id"
  end

  add_index "cats", ["category_id"], name: "index_cats_on_category_id", using: :btree
  add_index "cats", ["collection_id"], name: "index_cats_on_collection_id", using: :btree

  create_table "collections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "label"
  end

  add_foreign_key "cats", "categories"
  add_foreign_key "cats", "collections"
end
```

Here is the source code (a bit modified)
https://bitbucket.org/Paprikas/testrelation/overview

Comment: Can you share your database schema for those three models?

Comment: Just a note, the convention for your join model would be CategoryCollection instead of Cat.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails ActiveAdmin nested form has\_one accepts\_attributes\_for formtastic issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159884/rails-activeadmin-nested-form-has-one-accepts-attributes-for-formtastic-issue)

Comment: @penner I've added schema. PS. even index page (admin/categories) fail to open without id in `cats` table. So I enable it. But edit still not work.
About note - yeah, I know, Just remove everything to beat this without extra words.

Comment: About relevant issue: I do not need any possibility to edit nested fields. I need to assign records only.